# view in multiview timeout

Tags: .net, asp.net, multiview

Basically what I want to do is "timeout" a view.  Similar to a javascript redirect after a certain amount of time except instead of redirecting, switching to a different view in the multiview.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MultiView doesn't have a client-side API, the way to do this is to manually create a __doPostBack call with the multiview ID as the source:

```
__doPostBack('<%= multiview.UniqueID %>', 'switch');
```

The second parameter is the event name/args; you can manually check this on the postback via:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && 
    Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].EndsWith(multiview.ID) && 
    Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "switch")
```

And then switch the current view; there may already be a built-in command name to do this, I am not sure of that.